# Rewriting uncorrelated subquery to correlated subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, correlated-subquery

I am working with a default oracle `scott` database with additional table PROJECT, where there are two columns: `projectno` and `empno`.

I want to select names of employees with the highest salaries for each project.

I know how to do it with uncorrelated subquery:

```
SELECT p.projno, 
       e.sal, 
       e.ename
  FROM emp e 
 INNER 
  JOIN proj_emp p 
    ON e.empno = p.empno
 WHERE (e.sal, p.projno) 
    IN (SELECT MAX(e.sal), 
               p.projno 
          FROM emp e INNER JOIN proj_emp p 
            ON e.empno = p.empno
         GROUP BY p.projno)
```

However, i was asked to do it with a correlated subquery written in a `WHERE` clause, but i am wondering if it is possible?

Comment: Were you also asked to do this without window functions?

Comment: In an exercise instruction all what was said was to names of employees with the highest salaries for each project with a correlated subquery in a `WHERE` caluse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT p.projno, e.sal, e.ename,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p.projno ORDER BY e.sal DESC) AS Seq
      FROM emp e INNER JOIN
           proj_emp p 
           ON e.empno = p.empno
     ) t
WHERE Seq = 1;
```

**EDIT :** If you want to do it with correlated subquery then i would rewrite your query to make *correlated* :

```
SELECT p.projno, e.sal, e.ename
FROM emp e INNER JOIN 
     proj_emp p 
     ON e.empno = p.empno
WHERE e.sal = (SELECT MAX(e1.sal)
               FROM emp e1 INNER JOIN 
                    proj_emp p1 
                    ON e1.empno = p1.empno
               WHERE p1.projno = p.projno
              );
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, that in exercise instruction it was said to write correlated subquery in `WHERE` clause

Comment: I know, but a `correlated subquery` is required. I used `uncorrelated subquery`

Comment: Great! That is a solution, that i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT projno, sal, ename
FROM (SELECT p.projno, e.sal, e.ename,
             MAX(e.sal) OVER (PARTITION BY p.projno) as max_sal
      FROM emp e INNER JOIN
           proj_emp p 
           ON e.empno = p.empno
     ) ps
WHERE sal = max_sal;
```